# Multiple animations interrupt/interfere with eachother

Tags: swift, swiftui

I attempted to apply multiple animations to an object, one that loops on a short timer and one that changes on a button press. After reducing it down to an example, it appears that multiple animations interfere with eachother (replacing all animations duration/repeatability with the most recently triggered.

Example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RectangleView: Shape {
    var height: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat> {
        get {
           AnimatablePair(height, width)
        }
        set {
            height = newValue.first
            width = newValue.second
        }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        var rect = CGRect()
        
        rect.size.width = self.width
        rect.size.height = self.height
        
        path.addRect(rect)
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var width: CGFloat = 100
    @State var height: CGFloat = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RectangleView(height: height, width: width)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 30).repeatForever(), value: height)
                .animation(.spring(response: 1, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 1), value: width)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    height = 200
                })
                
            Button("Add width via spring", action: {
                width += 10
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Expected: Rectangle continues to grow vertically linearly over 30 seconds after clicking 'add width' button.

Actual: Rectangle springs vertically over 1 second along with the width.

Comment: You're right, the answer I posted won't solve the issue. I had misread, apologies. 
You're going to need `AnimatableModifier` (or a modifier that conforms to both `Animatable` and `ViewModifier` b/c `AnimatableModifier` is deprecated). 

With this you can save the position of the animation and continue it where it left off,  because the `height` variable is immediately set to 200, SwiftUI only animates the visual.
When you the `width` it redraws the view according to new value of `200`.

I'm unable to write up a stub right now, so I'll post this as a comment and delete the wrong answer.